# Maps not showing in the RStudio Viewer when using plotly in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-plotly, ggplotly

I've made a map using ggplot2 in R. I am now trying to use plotly so that I can make it more interactive (and in particular use tooltips). However, anything I try ends up with me just getting a blank viewer panel in RStudio. I am able to view other things with plotly (for e.g. a basic line chart), but not maps.

For the sake of being reproducible, I am also trying using this basic map taking code from [here](http://eriqande.github.io/rep-res-web/lectures/making-maps-with-R.html).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

usa <- map_data("usa")
states <- map_data("state")

usa_map <- ggplot(data = states) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = region, group = group), color = "white") + 
  coord_fixed(1.3) +
  guides(fill=FALSE)
```

This plots me a map, just how I want it.

Next, so far I have tried this:

```
ggplotly(usa_map)
```

And this:

```
usa_map_view <- plotly_build(usa_map)
usa_map_view
```

But both of these just give me the blank screen, without any error messages.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: This works but not in the RStudio viewer. You have to open in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. As [Stephane Laurent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1100107/st%C3%A9phane-laurent) mentioned, it can be viewed in the browser.

This is what I got in the browser. It has all the states listed on the right(scrollable list).
[image: Plot]

You can view in browser by clicking "open in new window" in "viewer".

[image: Open in new window]

Comment: Simple as that! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped.